# Горячие клавиши для переключения в редакторе разметки Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Для того чтобы в редакторе макета перейти в файл XML нужно использовать Ctrl+B.

Ничего подобного для обратной операции (вернуться в Design) я не нашла.

И вообще, если вдруг кто нибудь знает клавиши которые позволяют переключаться между Design-Split-Code (Так в новой версии студии называются эти окна)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переключаться между режимами:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd>

Назначить свои сочетания можно в File - Settings - Keymap.

Comment: Как называется данная функция?